# Как в Yii2 ActiveDataProvider отсортировать записи по нескольким критериям?

Tags: php, yii2

Мне необходимо в **ActiveDataProvider** положить записи, отсортированные по какому то критерию (например, по алфавиту) сначала при положительной цене товара, а потом по тому же критерию, но при нулевой цене товара.
Пробовал написать два **ActiveDataProvider**, а затем соединить их в один, но так не работает, да и неправильно, судя по всему.

```
$notAvailableDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider($dataProvider);
$notAvailableDataProvider->query->andWhere('`price` = ' . '0');
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider($dataProvider, $notAvailableDataProvider);
```

Подскажите как решить эту задачу? Важно в конечном счете получить именно **ActiveDataProvider**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вижу несколько вариантов.

### **Первый:**

`ActiveDataProvider` предоставляет данные, получая их в ответе вызова запроса, которым Вы его конфигурируете. Запрос должен быть объектом типа `yii\db\QueryInterface`. Вы должны сконфигурировать свой `ActiveDataProvider` таким экземпляром, который получал бы уже отсортированные нужным образом данные, сделать это можно используя `UNION`. *Sql* запрос должен получиться плюс-минус таким:

```
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE price > 0 ORDER BY title ASC)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE price = 0 ORDER BY title ASC);
```

Т.е., как это и предполагает `UNION`, вы объединяете вывод двух запросов на выборку. В первом запросе Вы выбираете товары с положительной ценой, во втором с нулевой. В двух запросах указываете одинаковый критерий сортировки.

Еще раз:

- создаете объект запроса (например, `ActiveQuery` или `Query`).
- используя интерфейс созданного объекта, описываете *sql* запрос, который содержит в себе выражение `UNION`, которое объединяет две необходимые Вам выборки.
- конфигурируете созданым объектом экземпляр `ActiveDataProvider` и работаете с ним.

У этого подхода есть свои недостатки, но очень вероятно, что Вам он полностью подойдет.

### **Второй:**

Отказываемся от идеи, что

> Важно в конечном счете получить именно ActiveDataProvider

Думаем иначе: *в конечном счете нужно получить объект, который реализует интерфейс `yii\data\DataProviderInterface`*.

К слову это более правильный с точки зрения объектно-ориентированного дизайна подход: *модули Вашего приложение не должны зависеть от конкретных реализаций, но должны полагаться на интерфейсы.*

Далее, создаем свой класс, который имплементирует `yii\data\DataProviderInterface`.

Описываем его конструктор так, чтобы он принимал на вход коллекцию экземпляров типа `yii\data\DataProviderInterface`, которые сохраняем в поле класса.
Реализуем методы, описанные в интерфейсе, делегируя их выполнение поочередно каждому из переданных в конструкторе экземпляров `yii\data\DataProviderInterface`, а в самом классе собираем их результаты работы, обрабатываем и возвращаем клиенту.

На клинте: создаем 2 объекта `ActiveDataProvider`, каждый из которых сконфигурирован одним отдельным *sql* запросом (первый получает товары с положительной ценой, второй с нулевой), собираем их в коллекцию. Создаем объект написаного нами класса, передавая ему в конструктор эту коллекцию. Дальше работаем с экземпляром нашего класса так же, как работали бы с `ActiveDataProvider`.

**Второй вариант сложнее, но предоставляет гораздо больше возможностей для гибкого расширения функционала приложения в дальнейшем.** В первом варианте присутствует *некий неявный хардкод* - Вы руками указываете, общий критерий сортировки, поменять его на ходу в рантайме будет затруднительно. Во втором же, Вы можете конфигурировать элементы коллекции общим объектом `yii\data\Sort`, можете конфигурировать их разными, при этом принимая решения об этом по ходу исполнения программы, отталкиваясь от параметров запроса, или контекста состояния приложения. По большему счету, первый вариант тоже можно развить до возможности конфигурации в рантайме, но там это будет в лучшем случае менее элегантно, в худшем - пополам с костылями. Но в целом, думаю, что Вам пока вполне может подойти именно первый вариант.

Comment: Благодарю вас за развернутый ответ. Разложили все "по полочкам"